# Selecting a point on MATLAB figure and putting label exactly on that point

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have an image in matlab and I prompt the user to select certain points on that image. So I am using the getpts method to do it. So it is working fine but I just want to represent the point the user clicked on the image with an X. However, the X is not on the point I clicked but to the side of it.

Anyone knows how to make it dead on? Here are the code that I am using and some pictures to represent it more explicitly.

Thanks you

Code:

```
[x_Ls y_Ls] = getpts(handles.axes1)
handles.Ls = [x_Ls y_Ls]
setappdata(0,'Lsvalue',[x_Ls y_Ls])
text(x_Ls,y_Ls,'X' , 'FontSize', 16, 'FontWeight', 'Bold', 'Color',    'k','Parent',handles.axes1);
```

[image: Should be Picture]

[image: What it is]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is, that `text` containing an "X" is aligned such, that its lower left corner is at `[x_Ls, y_Ls]`. Things should improve if you set the `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` to `"center"`. 
But since fonts always define certain boundaries around the "visible" letter, you'd have a really hard time to get the "X" center to be exactly where you want it.

If you want the "X" centered right at the defined points, simply using `plot` instead of `text` should be easier:

```
plot(x_Ls, y_Ls, 'x', 'MarkerSize', 10, 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'b', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'b')
```

Should produce an "X", right at the point you clicked on.
You might have to increase the markersize...

Comment: Thank you! it works. However, you do need the following: hold (handles.axes1,'on') ryte before the plot statement